# Windows 11 sudden issue with Windows Sandbox and Windows Subsystem for Android

Tags: windows, windows-11, virtualization, windows-sandbox, windows-subsystem-for-android

For some days now, my Windows Sandbox & Windows Subsystem for Android, stopped working and i can't find a way to solve the issue after trying many suggestions i found on the internet.

Windows Sandbox after clicking to open it, 3 minutes later gives me error:

> The Container Manager service or one of its dependencies is not
> running. Error 0x8007041d. The service did not respond to the start or
> control request in a timely fashion. Would you like to submit feedback
> about this issue?

Windows Subsystem for Android after clicking to open it, 30 seconds later gives me error:

> Make sure that virtualization is enabled in the BIOS and Virtual
> Machine Platform is turned on for your PC. For more info, visit
> support.

-Now first of all, both used to work without problems for years and they suddenly stopped.

-Running on a Surface Book 2.

-In Windows features, Hyper-V is checked, Virtual Machine Platform is checked, Windows Hypervision Platform is checked, Windows Sandbox is checked.
I Tried to uncheck them, reboot, then check them again, reboot again. Nothing changed.

-Container Manager Service in services is in "Running" status. If i click the service to stop in order to start it again, it remains in "Stopping" status until i reboot the computer again to return in "Running" status.

-I tried the most discussed fix i found on the internet, running in cmd command "bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto", nothing changed.

-I run "Sfc /scannow" and "Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth", no problems found.

Of course, restoring windows, is not an option for me.

Any suggestions to try to fix this issue, would much appreciated.

I am using Windows 11 22H2 (OS Build 22621.2792)

Comment: Please check the UEFI firmware to ensure any/all virtualization options are enabled

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks, i've already checked. Yes it's enabled. Before issue appears, it was working without problems. Didn't make any change to UEFI since then.

Comment: "restoring windows, is not an option for me." Why not? Downloading the Windows ISO and reinstalling, *keeping files*, often is the fastest way to fix an issue.

Comment: What is the contents of `C:\programData\Microsoft\Windows\Containters\Sandboxes`? Is the `Container Manager Service` running?

Comment: You could try to uninstall both the Sandbox and Windows Subsystem for Android, then reinstall them in the correct order. A problem that might block this is that removing WSA also uninstalls the Amazon Appstore and any Android app you have previously installed.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Not so fast for me. I have over 100 software programs that need to be registered again and have many cutom settings that i need a month for the configuration if i won't forget something that i might regret. That's why restoring is not an option.

Comment: @Ramhound There is no folder "Sandboxes" inside Containers folder.

Comment: @harrymc Tried this too. Same issue after reinstalling.

Comment: My experience reinstalling w Window, **keeping files**, is that all applications and settings persist. However, if you fell that's unsafe, make a *drive image* first.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Ok but this should be the very last solution to any problem. I would love to hear any suggetions to try solve this issue before reaching the obvious one.